# I am trying to make a Windows batch file that searches my C Drive

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to make a windows batch file that searches my c drive for the filename i specify, and then display the full path to any file or folder that has the searched text in it to results.txt. I have experimented with several scripts but I have yet to be successful. I have only been using batch for the last two or so weeks and I am very new to it.
Example script i have been trying

```
echo off
title Search
set input=
set /p input=
find C:\%input% >> results.txt
pause
```

I have also tried using this script, which has worked to some degree.

```
title BROWSER
echo off
color 0a
:start
cls
echo To search for a file enter the filename below.
set input=
set /p input=Search:
cls
echo Are you sure %input% is correct?
set input2=
set /p input2=(Y/N)
if %input2%==Y start %input% && goto start 
if %input2%==N goto start
```

Although this doesn't write to a txt file and instead opens the file/folder.

Comment: Are you trying to find files by name or text strings within files?

Comment: I am open to both, but would prefer to search by name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand what the Windows `find` command does.  It does not find file names; it searches for text strings within files.  As you have it now, you should be getting a syntax error on the `find` command because it needs two inputs:  the text string to search for and the file(s) to search.  For example, what you might want to do is this:

```
find c:\%input% "%1"
```

The user would then enter something like this:

myfind *.txt

Your batch file would then prompt for the search string and search all files matching `*.txt`.

Personally, I wouldn't add `C:\` to the `find` command because that limits the batch file to working on the `C:` drive only.  I also wouldn't prompt for the string.  I would simply do this:

```
find "%1" "%2"
```

Users would then invoke it like this:

```
myfind somestring c:\*.txt
```

On the other hand, if you don't want to search for text strings within files but rather just find files by name, then all you need is the `dir` command with the `/s` option.  Your batch file would look something like this:

```
echo off
title Search
set input=
set /p input=
dir C:\%input% /s /b >> results.txt
pause
```

The `/s` option will cause `dir` to search the entire drive, and the `/b` option will give you only fully-qualified file names without the usual `dir` header and footers.

Comment: Thank you very much! I thought that the `find` command searched for file names. I kind of new what the `dir` command did, but i had never seen it used before.

Comment: @Lpowell on that note you can use the dir command with the /s switch that writes to a plain text file   `dir C:\ /s >directory.txt` and use the `findstr` or `find` command to grab path and filename, you can also use the `for` command for multiple (arrays) of search results.